# Conda Install all packages in a channel

Tags: anaconda, conda, arcgis

I am wondering if there is an easy way to install all packages that reside in a Conda Channel. To be specific I would like to install all packages from the ESRI channel.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and *all* is likely impossible anyway. The packages there range widely in date since last updated, so I highly doubt one could install *every* package into the same environment.